# Android FTP throught URL Output Stream

Tags: android, ftp, outputstream, urlconnection

I want to create an xml file from my program and upload it via FTP. I wrote a PC version and I'm adapting it for android. I have this code here that doesn't work, it always throughs an IO exeception over the URL connection.

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://foo:PASSWORD@foo.net/myfile.xml");
    URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
    OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream();
```

I have the configured the Internet access permission from the manifest. I just think it's weird that it works on the PC but not on my Android Emulator. Is it because I'm testing it form the Emulator? I'd rather avoid other FTP packages if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think android has any libraries to handle FTP built in. Thus, you'll either have to implement it on your own, or use a library.

You can use [edtftpj](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpj/)

Also you could take a look at [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) there are some blogs on how to get it working on android.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on a pc it should work on android, providing you have set the right permissions in your manifest. I have noticed that quite often, network doesn't work on an emulator, so you have to restart it. Have you tried on a device?

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Can you see what exception you get, or what happens when the data is written to the output stream? You sure you have the permission in the manifest right?

Comment: I get and IOExecption...something about FtpURLConnection.port() line:406. It happends on the urlc.getOutputStream() method